# Topic Challenge: Transitions

Tags: discussion, challenge

It's time for another **Community Building Challenge**!

After a couple months without a challenge, I think it's time to have another one. This challenge will revolve around [transitions](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/195/78).

> No community is static; communities grow and shrink, become more or less active, etc. How do we keep them functional when this happens? How do we add some structure to a community that's now too large to run by consensus? How do we migrate a community from one platform to another? (That's not a technical question but a community one.) How do we respond to shrinking -- or even dying -- communities?

We have some questions in in this scope already, but the idea behind this challenge is provide a broader base for these types of important questions. There is not a tag specific to this challenge.

As a reminder: It is completely acceptable to ask a question and provide an answer to the same question. We are here to share our knowledge.

If you have ideas for future topics, you can provide those at our topic suggestion [thread](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/community-building-topic-challenge-ideas-thread).

This challenge will run until March 19th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This challenge has been completed. We received one question for this challenge attracting one answer during the challenge time:

- [As a user, how can I stay on top of a fast-growing community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1081/83)  (growth)

---

Thanks to the participants of this event.

[image: profile for Jan Doggen at Community Building Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Monica Cellio at Community Building Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

Comment: And a [second answer](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1083/83) shortly after the challenge ended.  (I should have asked my question earlier; I wasn't tracking the deadline.)